# Android search in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to ask for help in a problem that I want to search for e-mail, according to the database, but it fails to process the received data. I want to receive something of value that the email is already in the database or not.

How do I process the result? Here's the code which try:

```
DatabaseReference reg = FirebaseReferenciak.reg;
reg.orderByChild("email").equalTo("email", etEmail.getText().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
            String value = map.get("name");
//Here is how do I check?
            //String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            dialog(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            dialog("error");
        }
    }
);
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

For that reason you'll need to loop over the children of the `DataSnapshot` that you receive in `onDataChange()`:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String value = childSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        dialog(value);
    }
}
```